# OData navigation use $expand instead of url /path

Tags: c#, rest, odata

I just started using OData and implementing it into my c# Web API project. The one thing which bothers me is that to load navigation property the `$expand` query is used instead of url /path.

For example, by rest api specification if we want to load entity with navigation table(parent->child) we usually call

```
/users/1/logs
```

result

```
{
"Id": 12254,
"ApiKey": 104254635,
"FirstName": "Joshua",
"LastName": "Marcus",
"DateStamp": "2019-06-11T06:43:11.897+03:00",
"TimeZone": "UTC",
"Logs":[
{"Id": 74216060, "Result": true, "DateStamp": "2019-06-11T06:51:17.487+03:00", "ConversionTime": 3,…},
{"Id": 74215748, "Result": false, "DateStamp": "2019-06-11T06:50:11.117+03:00", "ConversionTime": 3,…}
]
}
```

The OData to load navigation property use query parameters instead

```
/users/1?$expand=logs
```

That's a little bit weird and looks out of Rest API specification to query resources like this. Maybe someone could comment on this and give more information about why such a solution is used in OData and is it possible to use a common parent/child structure to query related records using OData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option [$expand](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/cs01/part1-protocol/odata-v4.01-cs01-part1-protocol.html#_Toc505771201) only tells the service to return your navigation elements *inline* with the result for your request to the parent entity. You should be able to access the `logs` entity set with your url `/users/1/logs`, and generally it should return an array of `log` entities, but without the parent entity properties. But if you want both your parent entity and the (expanded) logs in one request and result, you need to use the $expand option. Think of it as a way to reduce the number of queries when fetching hierarchical data sets. With $expand you can also decide which child navigation properties to expand (and to which level).

With this OData v2 test service you can for instance request a `Product` entity and use the $expand option to not just expand the Supplier, but all the products of the Supplier:

base url for the service: https://services.odata.org/V2/(S(readwrite))/OData/OData.svc/ (the service replaces part of its url with a randomized string, so you'll see a slightly modified version of this url once you open the base url in a browser).

and with the request to `Products(0)?$expand=Supplier/Products` you'll get the product with Id 0, its supplier inline with the product, and all products of the supplier inline with the supplier. If you however request `Products(0)/Supplier/Products`, you will only receive an array of `product` entities without the supplier data or properties of the product you initially requested (although it is also included in the list in this case).

Comment: Thank you for explaining that! So basically Rest API should be implemented as usual and OData just adds some query operators on top of the already implemented Rest API endpoints.